# The right way to call methods from other objects when they are siblings

Tags: javascript, oop

I have several javascript objects constructed with the following structure. I don't know if this is right or the structure is not recomendable, but I'd like to know how to call that method from the specified place:

```
function Graphic_Interface (){
    var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //I want to call game > obj > doSomething() from here; how can I do it?
    })
}
function Another_Object(){
    this.doSomething = function(){
        console.log('doing something');
    };
}
function Game (){
    var gi = new Graphic_Interface();
    var obj = new Another_Object();
}
var game = new Game();
```

Is it possible? is the construction right? is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `Game.obj.doSomething(); `?

Comment: @LearningProcess Nope - `obj` is a local of `Game` (similar to a private method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly (assuming `Game` is used as a constructor) you want to pass the `Game` object to the `Graphic_Interface`.

Something like

```
function Graphic_Interface (game){
    var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        game.obj.do_something();
    })
}
function Another_Object(){
    this.doSomething = function(){
        console.log('doing something');
    };
}
function Game (){
    var gi = new Graphic_Interface(this);
    this.obj = new Another_Object(); // Note saving as member
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This *is* one way of handling this problem.

Comment: Nope - obj is a local of Game (similar to a private method). lol

Comment: @LearningProcess Actually, nope - that's why Motti used `this`. It's a member now, not a local.

Comment: This works, of course, but Is this the right way to do this? Or the structure of objects and instances should be completly different so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: @Vandervals, that depends on the design of your application. I would think that this is a completely reasonable way to do it.